# A bound for the products of a bounded sequence $\{x_{k}\}$ with $\lim_{t\to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{t}(1-x_{k})=0$

Tags: convergence-divergence, infinite-product, upper-lower-bounds

Let $\{x_{k}\}$ be a bounded sequence with $x_{k}\neq 1$, and if
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{t\to \infty}\prod_{k=0}^{t}(1-x_{k})=0.
\end{align*} 
The question is can we infer
\begin{align*}
 \prod_{k=0}^{t}x_{k}< \alpha |x_{0}|2^{t}
\end{align*}
for some $\alpha>0$？

Here is my initial thought: In the special case where $x_{k}$ is a constant, then $x_{k}\in (0, 2)$, and the inequality holds.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the reminding.

Comment: Hi! I see you changed the question quite substantially in the third revision. I also see that two users had answered the original question in the meantime. I understand you may have misformulated your question initially (the same has occured to me), but given the timeline of events I suggest you to roll back this question to revision #2. It is perfectly ok to ask a new question, even if it's only slightly different.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I think I rever the question and ask a new one.

Comment: You're welcome. I changed the title to reflect the question better, if you're fine with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even excluding the case where any $x$ is $1$ (and the case $x_0=0$ which I assume you also intended to exclude), still the answer is negative.  Just have $x_k$ alternate between 2.9 and 1.5, for example.  The product of $x$ grows exponentially with base $\sqrt{2.9\cdot1.5}=\sqrt{4.35}>2$ and the product of any two consecutive $1-x$ is $0.95<1$ so that product is $0$.

I should also note that the $|x_0|$ in your proposed conclusion is a pleonasm since $\alpha >0$ is arbitrary and since you need to exclude $x_0=0$ anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot infer that.  For example, let $x_0=1$ and $x_j=3$ for all other $j$.

Comment: Sorry, I should have add $x_{k}\neq 1$.

Comment: Please delete this answer as it is now outdated.